# How do i create a .psv file inside each sub-folder that i created? i am using bourne shell script

Tags: shell

I am trying to create a single csv file in each corresponding sub-folder that I created.
For example, if i created a folder named Grass, there supposed to be a grass_pokemon.csv file which includes all the grass pokemons inside that folder. But based on code i have, **it creates sub-folders and csv files separately.**
BTW: the source file pokemon.csv file contains all the pokemons, and it is within the same folder as all sub-folders(Grass, Water...).

````
#This is a comment
if [ $# = 0 ]; then
    echo Error\: Missing Filename
    echo USAGE\: sh fileCheck.sh \<pokemon.csv\>
    exit
fi
if [ -f $1 ]; then
    echo FILE \"$1\" is found
    if [ -r $1 ]; then
    for i in Water Electric Rock Fire Ground Ghoust Dragon Grass Steel Bug Fightng Fairy Dark Ice Normal Poision Psychic Flying
    do
        `mkdir $i`
        for j in $i
        do
            `cat pokemon.csv|grep $j >> pokemon_$j.csv`
        done
    done
    fi  
fi```
````

Comment: Thanks in advance for all answering!

Comment: If it's a Bourne shell script, please add the appropriate shebang at the start.

Comment: What is a PSV file please?

Comment: Remove the `\`` (backticks) around `mkdir $i` and remove the `for j in $i` loop and remove the `\`` (backticks) surronuding `cat pokemon.csv|grep $j >> pokemon_$j.csv` and change `$j` to `$i`. You do not want **command substitution**, you simply want `mkdir $i` and `cat pokemon.csv|grep $i >> pokemon_$i.csv` for each  (or better `grep $i pokemon.csv >> pokemon_$i.csv`, `cat` is unnecessary) Since you are processing `$i` one by one, `j=$i` so `j` is superfluous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from my comment, you are using **command substitution** improperly. When you surround commands with (``) (backticks), the result of the command substitution is the result of the command itself. The command runs in a subshell and the result is returned to the current shell as text. With `mkdir $i`, the command substitution is wholly unnecessary. The same for `cat pokemon.csv|grep $j >> pokemon_$j.csv` (note - it is better and more readable to do command substitution with `$(...)` instead of backticks)

Further, since you are processing each word in `Water Electric Rock Fire Ground Ghoust Dragon Grass Steel Bug Fightng Fairy Dark Ice Normal Poision Psychic Flying` one at at time in your outer loop, your inner `j` loop is likewise unnecessary as `j=$i`. You can remove that loop entirely.

`cat pokemon.csv|grep $i >> pokemon_$i.csv` is a ***UUOc*** (*Unnecessary Use Of `cat`*). There is no need to `cat` a file to `grep`, simply `grep` the file, e.g.

```
grep $i pokemon.csv >> pokemon_$i.csv
```

Lastly, every variable expansion within `[...]` must be double-quoted (save and except the single numeric expansions like `$#` -- though it is still wise to quote it all, e.g. `"$#"`). Otherwise, any variable expansion containing whitespace will cause `test` to fail. You can also validate your directory creation and exit in the event you don't have write permission in the current directory, e.g.

```
        mkdir $i || {
            printf "error: directory creation failed.\n" >&2
            exit 1
        }
```

(**note:** `"$i"` MUST be double-quoted to avoid word-splitting)

Putting it altogether, you could do something like the following, but note, your use of the positional parameter `"$1"` to pass the filename as an argument to the program looks like you intended to replace `"pokemon.csv"` with `"$1"` -- otherwise what you are attempting to pass as `"$1"` is unclear. That said, a literal updating of your code so it is correct without the `"$1"` substitution would be:

(**edit:** cleaned up quoting of `echo "..."` originally copied verbatim from the question)

```
#!/bin/sh

#This is a comment
if [ $# = 0 ]; then
    echo "Error: Missing Filename"
    echo "USAGE: sh fileCheck.sh <pokemon.csv>"
    exit
fi
if [ -f "$1" ]; then
    echo "FILE '$1' is found"
    if [ -r "$1" ]; then
    for i in Water Electric Rock Fire Ground Ghoust Dragon Grass Steel Bug Fightng Fairy Dark Ice Normal Poision Psychic Flying
    do
        mkdir "$i" || {
            printf "error: directory creation failed.\n" >&2
            exit 1
        }
        grep "$i" pokemon.csv >> "$i/pokemon_$i.csv"
    done
    fi  
fi
```

(**note:** above if you want to place the new `pokemon_$i.csv` in the new directory your create with `mkdir "$i"`, you need to prepend the directory to the filename where output is redirected, e.g. `"$i/pokemon_$i.csv"` as used above -- change as needed)

If you did intend to use the filename passed as the first argument instead of hardcoding `"pokemon.csv"` you would need to update the line with `grep` to:

```
        grep "$i" "$1" >> "$i/${1}_$i.csv"
```

Let me know if you have further questions, and if you need to processes the list in some other manner that was apparent in your question, just drop a comment below.

Comment: That was an elegant answer! For duplication of cat part, i copied from my professor's note so i do not want to change them, since that what he taught us to do. However, i got another issue when i proceed with this assignment.

Comment: If it's a short issue, just add another comment and I'll answer there if I can. If it is a long issue, then open another question and I'll help there.

Comment: I just finished my question and posted it. If you don't mind to have a look.

Comment: Sure, let me find it.

Comment: `echo Error\: Missing Filename` is bad practice, use `echo 'Error: Missing Filename'` instead. Similarly for the other `echo` lines - quote the string being passed to echo. In particular `echo FILE \"$1\" is found` is particularly bad as it's leaving `$1` unquoted and so open to word splitting, filename expansion, etc. with associated buginess and security issues.