# How can i express "3rd field in each line of the pokemon.csv file" with cut program?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

According to (https://gist.github.com/armgilles/194bcff35001e7eb53a2a8b441e8b2c6#file-pokemon-csv), each pokemon might have 2 types: type1 & type2.
After i created all the csv files, when i examine them, i noticed that it would add pokemons that type2 matches with i(for i in Water, Electric...etc).
For example, if i created a folder named Grass,  for all pokemons which Type 1 is
Grass, then add all lines that contain Type 1 = Grass Pokemon into the pokemon_grass.csv file.
It should only take care of type1.
I am trying to use cut program to do this.
Is there a way to simplify my for loop conditions? I mean instead of list all types(Water, Grass...), can i do something like
`` for i in `pokemon.csv | cut -d , -f 3` `` which takes only 3rd field in each line?

````
#This is a comment
if [ $# = 0 ]; then
    echo Error\: Missing Filename
    echo USAGE\: sh fileCheck.sh \<pokemon.csv\>
    exit
fi
if [ -f $1 ]; then
    echo FILE \"$1\" is found
    if [ -r $1 ]; then
    for i in Water Electric Rock Fire Ground Ghoust Dragon Grass Steel Bug Fightng Fairy Dark Ice Normal Poision Psychic Flying
    do
        mkdir $i
        `cat pokemon.csv|grep $i | cut -d , -f 3 >> $i/pokemon_$i.csv`
    done
    fi  
fi```
````

Comment: Why do you have the command inside backticks? That's used for assigning the result of a command to a variable.

Comment: That was what my course note presented. So i just copied it.

Comment: Since the output is redirected, the backticks expand to nothing. The course is wrong.

Comment: Yes, you can use that `for` loop.

Comment: @Barmar we ran into some of those issues with his course in the [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68787422/3422102). Seems there is good reason to be a bit skeptical about the teacher `:)`

Comment: @朱旭翔 - We need you to show about 10 or so lines from `pokemon.csv` so we can see how it is formatted to help you separate the fields. Just edit your question and copy/paste 10 or so lines putting `\`\`\`none` on the line before the data and `\`\`\`` on the line after so it formats as fixed text. (never mind I followed the link)

Comment: Are you really supposed to end up with say `Grass/pokemon_Grass.csv` containing multiple lines that are just `"Grass"`? That is what repeatedly redirecting the 3rd field to the file will do:

Comment: Copy/paste your shell script (and any other shell script you write until you learn the fundamentals) into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about. The result won't necessarily be error-free but at least it won't have the errors that tool can detect so then we won't have to see and tell you about them. [edit] your question to contain concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want to do is separate the `pokemon.csv` file into the separate directory named for the `type 1` pokemon (3rd field) and write each record with the same `type 1` pokemon to the file, then the correct tool for the job is `awk`. Single-pass, simply build the `mkdir -p` and `touch` command to create each file needed and pipe the command to the shell. Then simply redirect each record to the proper directory and name, e.g.

```
awk -F, '
    NR > 1 { 
        if ($3 in a) {  # if 3rd field exists in array a, already created
            print $0 > $3"/pokemon_"$3".csv"    # print record to file
            next                                # get next record
        }
        a[$3]++         # increment value in array at index of 3rd field
        # build command line to create directory and empty file, pipe to shell
        printf "mkdir -p \047%s\047 && touch \047%s\047\n", $3, $3"/pokemon_"$3".csv" | "sh"
        close ("sh")    # close shell
        print $0 > $3"/pokemon_"$3".csv"        # print record to file
    }
' pokemon.csv
```

**Example Use/Output**

Just select-copy and middle-mouse paste the command above into an xterm where the present working directory contains `pokemon.csv`, e.g.

```
$ awk -F, '
>     NR > 1 {
>         if ($3 in a) {  # if 3rd field exists in array a, already created
>             print $0 > $3"/pokemon_"$3".csv"    # print 3rd filed to file
>             next                                # get next record
>         }
>         a[$3]++         # increment value in array at index of 3rd field
>         # build command line to create directory and empty file, pipe to shell
>         printf "mkdir -p \047%s\047 && touch \047%s\047\n", $3, $3"/pokemon_"$3".csv" | "sh"
>         close ("sh")    # close shell
>         print $0 > $3"/pokemon_"$3".csv"        # print 3rd field to file
>     }
> ' pokemon.csv
```

**Result:**

```
$ tree
.
├── Bug
│   └── pokemon_Bug.csv
├── Dark
│   └── pokemon_Dark.csv
├── Dragon
│   └── pokemon_Dragon.csv
├── Electric
│   └── pokemon_Electric.csv
├── Fairy
│   └── pokemon_Fairy.csv
├── Fighting
│   └── pokemon_Fighting.csv
├── Fire
│   └── pokemon_Fire.csv
├── Flying
│   └── pokemon_Flying.csv
├── Ghost
│   └── pokemon_Ghost.csv
├── Grass
│   └── pokemon_Grass.csv
├── Ground
│   └── pokemon_Ground.csv
├── Ice
│   └── pokemon_Ice.csv
├── Normal
│   └── pokemon_Normal.csv
├── Poison
│   └── pokemon_Poison.csv
├── Psychic
│   └── pokemon_Psychic.csv
├── Rock
│   └── pokemon_Rock.csv
├── Steel
│   └── pokemon_Steel.csv
├── Water
│   └── pokemon_Water.csv
```

Where, for example, `Bug/pokemon_Bug.csv` contains:

```
$ cat Bug/pokemon_Bug.csv
10,Caterpie,Bug,,195,45,30,35,20,20,45,1,False
11,Metapod,Bug,,205,50,20,55,25,25,30,1,False
12,Butterfree,Bug,Flying,395,60,45,50,90,80,70,1,False
13,Weedle,Bug,Poison,195,40,35,30,20,20,50,1,False
14,Kakuna,Bug,Poison,205,45,25,50,25,25,35,1,False
15,Beedrill,Bug,Poison,395,65,90,40,45,80,75,1,False
15,BeedrillMega Beedrill,Bug,Poison,495,65,150,40,15,80,145,1,False
46,Paras,Bug,Grass,285,35,70,55,45,55,25,1,False
47,Parasect,Bug,Grass,405,60,95,80,60,80,30,1,False
48,Venonat,Bug,Poison,305,60,55,50,40,55,45,1,False
49,Venomoth,Bug,Poison,450,70,65,60,90,75,90,1,False
123,Scyther,Bug,Flying,500,70,110,80,55,80,105,1,False
127,Pinsir,Bug,,500,65,125,100,55,70,85,1,False
127,PinsirMega Pinsir,Bug,Flying,600,65,155,120,65,90,105,1,False
165,Ledyba,Bug,Flying,265,40,20,30,40,80,55,2,False
166,Ledian,Bug,Flying,390,55,35,50,55,110,85,2,False
167,Spinarak,Bug,Poison,250,40,60,40,40,40,30,2,False
168,Ariados,Bug,Poison,390,70,90,70,60,60,40,2,False
193,Yanma,Bug,Flying,390,65,65,45,75,45,95,2,False
204,Pineco,Bug,,290,50,65,90,35,35,15,2,False
205,Forretress,Bug,Steel,465,75,90,140,60,60,40,2,False
<... snip ...>
595,Joltik,Bug,Electric,319,50,47,50,57,50,65,5,False
596,Galvantula,Bug,Electric,472,70,77,60,97,60,108,5,False
616,Shelmet,Bug,,305,50,40,85,40,65,25,5,False
617,Accelgor,Bug,,495,80,70,40,100,60,145,5,False
632,Durant,Bug,Steel,484,58,109,112,48,48,109,5,False
636,Larvesta,Bug,Fire,360,55,85,55,50,55,60,5,False
637,Volcarona,Bug,Fire,550,85,60,65,135,105,100,5,False
649,Genesect,Bug,Steel,600,71,120,95,120,95,99,5,False
664,Scatterbug,Bug,,200,38,35,40,27,25,35,6,False
665,Spewpa,Bug,,213,45,22,60,27,30,29,6,False
666,Vivillon,Bug,Flying,411,80,52,50,90,50,89,6,False
```

As mentioned, you can do the same with a shell loop -- but that will be horribly inefficient, grepping the file repeatedly for every type-1 name in your list. With `awk` -- it handles it all for you. (`awk` is the Swiss Army-Knife of text processing) See [GNU Awk - User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents)

Comment: Ah, I got you. That make sense. Will update there.

Comment: thanks for your answer! but what does `\047%s\047 && touch \047%s\047\n"` mean?

Comment: That is how you use `'`  (single-quote) in a POSIX string. If you look at [ASCII Table](https://www.asciitable.com/) at hex 0x47 -- it is the single-quote. So the string snipped in your comment is `" ... '%s' && touch '%s'\n"` That way if `"$3"` contains any whitespace, the string you build with `"mkdir -p \047%s\047 && touch \047%s\047\n"` protects whatever is expanded from `$3` and  `$3"/pokemon_"$3".csv"` with the `'%s'` format specifier to `printf()`

Answer (score 1):

Without sample input/output it's an untested guess but is this what you're trying to do?

```
sort -t',' -k3,3 -k1,1n pokemon.csv |
awk -F',' '
    NR == 1 {
        hdr = $0
        next
    }
    $3 != prev  {
        close(out)
        system("mkdir -p \047" $3 "\047")
        out = $3 "/pokemon_" $3 ".csv"
        print hdr > out
        prev = $3
    }
    { print > out }
'
```

The above only has 1 output file open at a time and so it cannot fail with a "too many open files" error in any awk no matter how many $3s exist in your input and it won't slow other awks down having to manage opening/closing files in the background.

It's not at all clear why you'd want your output to be in `$3/pokemon_$3.csv` instead of either `$3/pokemon.csv` or `./pokemon_$3.csv` - making it unique to $3 in both the directory and the file name seems redundant.

Comment: He he he... I like the `system(..)` touch.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks. I notice you used `print "mkdir ..." | "sh"; close("sh")` instead of `system("mkdir ...")` - the pipe syntax is for when you have multiple lines you want to be processed by some command before you close it (e.g. `print | "sort"`) or you want to specify some shell that;s not the default one used by awk in a system() call or you want to use a co-process in gawk. Otherwise, if you just want to call a shell command using the default shell to do one immediate task, that's what system() is for.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually listing all types, you can use use `cut -d, -f3 pokemon.csv | sort -u | while read -r i; do ...; done`. However, that would only be a minimal improvement.

Right now you read `pokemon.csv` over and over again (one time for each type). It would be better to read the file only once, as follows:

```
while IFS=, read -r id name type1 otherFields
    mkdir -p "$type1"
    echo "$id,$name,$type1,$otherFields" >> "$type1/pokemon_$type1.csv"
done < pokemon.csv
```

Comment: You saying after `-r`, i need to list all colunms one by one like Atk Sp Def?

Comment: No, `otherFields` is *not* a placeholder. The script looks literally like this and is complete. When there are more fields than variables, `read` reads all remaining fields into the last variable.